# Number of parameters in Resnet-50

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, python, keras

I'm using Keras, and I am struggling to know how many parameters `Resnet-50` has. [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/api/applications/) says around `25M`, while if I use `model.param_count()` when loading a `Resnet-50` model, it says `234M`.
Which one is correct? I'm confused.

`model.summary` prints this:

```
Total params: 234,355,586
Trainable params: 210,767,874
Non-trainable params: 23,587,712
```

Comment: call model.summary, there's no way it hat 230 million trainable parameters

Comment: The number of parameters depends on your input size and number of classes. Like @Brale_ said call `model.summary()` to be sure.

Comment: How is `model.summary()` different from `param_count()`?

Comment: `Total params: 234,355,586 ...
Trainable params: 210,767,874...
Non-trainable params: 23,587,712`

Comment: Can you post your entire code that lead to this param count?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50

resnet_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')

#resnet_model.count_params()
resnet_model.summary()
```

> Total params: 25,636,712
>   
> Trainable params: 25,583,592
>   
> Non-trainable params: 53,120

**Check your code once to be sure that it is ResNet50**

Answer (score 1):

Call `model_name.summary()`

This will return you the correct value for the total number of parameters.

Comment: That's what I did (look above). It's a saved fine-tuned model from ResNet-50. It shouldn't change the number of parameters, right?

Comment: Well, typically a ResNet-50 contains around 25.6 million parameters including trainable parameters, maybe you didn't load the correct model, the number of parameters should never be that much